# Time to infinitive or time for gerund

Tags: gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive, to-for

Please consider the following constructions:
1. It's time to launch it
2. It's time for launching it
3. It's time for being taught this lesson
4. It's time to be taught this lesson
Which one(s) is/are not idiomatic or even wrong?

Comment: Neither 'it's time to be taught this lesson' nor 'it's time for being taught this lesson' are idiomatic. Even 'It's time that we were taught this lesson' sounds like something people aren't likely to say. 'It's time that they were taught this lesson' is another matter. /  'It's time that we were taught how to differentiate a function of a function' sounds more reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression "*It's time...*" generally refers to the present time on the clock or calendar at which something is to start. If this is the case, then the continuation is much more likely† to use the *to infinitive*.

For example: *it's time to eat*, *it's time to go*,  *it's time to end the lockdown*.

The word *time* also refers to a duration rather than a starting point. For example, *there will be time for eating after the show*. In such a case  the emphasis could be seen as more on the ongoing nature of the action than on its starting point.

But even in this second durational sense of the word *time*, the *to infinitive* is more common.

As to your two examples, the *to infinitive* version in each case is much the better choice.

---

† This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=time%20to%20eat%2Ctime%20for%20eating&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctime%20to%20eat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20for%20eating%3B%2Cc0) compares *time for eating* and *time to eat*.

A simple Google search returns 6.5 million hits for *time for eating* and 278 million for *time to eat*.

Comment: So, we can use *time+gerund* only for duration (tho using *to infinitive* is better even in this case), right?

Comment: There is no black and white rule here. A parent could say: _OK kids, it's time for eating!_ But much more likely is _It's time to eat!_

Comment: Got it. Thanks shoe.

Comment: one more thing. Does the construction *for being past participle* exist in this case?

Comment: @Fadli Sheikh. The passive construction _being + past participle_ exists. For example: _There is a strong argument for being vaccinated_. But since _vaccinate_ is a _'punctual'_ verb (unlike _eat_ which is _'durative'_), the _to infinitive_ is much more likely in the _it's time to..._ expression: _It's time to be vaccinated_. (? _It's time for being vaccinated._)

Comment: It's time *to be/for being* beaten up, guys. In the above sentence, it is just too weird to use *for being*, right?

Comment: Yes, that's weird, in more ways than one. In general, the infinitive form will be the best choice in a very large majority of cases.